# Why is jquery datepicker only working once within the same form?

Tags: jquery

I am setting up a request quote from that is using a pickup date and return date.  The jquery datepicker widget works great on pickup date but is not working on return date. Is there any reason why it would not work twice within the same form?  I am using the same code posted at http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
</head>
   .
   .
   .
<body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
                      } );
     </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: You only set the datepicker to work on the element with the ID of datepicker, and you can't re-use IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class instead id.

```
  <p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
```

And do not forget the change script for class;

```
<script>
        $( function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
                      } );
     </script>
```

Comment: Thank so much.  I had an idea it was that but wasn't sure.